# javascript array split undefined

Tags: javascript

i'm trying to work out why i get error undefined from my function. It works at the start but if i change the text "Text Here" in the input around it will than return undefined?

I just started to learn javascript today and i don't know why and was hoping someone could maybe help me i think my problem is tagLength?

What i'm trying to do is display the text/words one by one from one input to another input using split and an array.

```js
var tagButton = document.getElementById("buttonTag");
tagButton.addEventListener("click", partyTagChange);

var partTag = null,
  tagLength = 0,
  tagMaxLength = 0;

function partyTagChange() {
  clearInterval(partTag);
  if (partTag !== null) {
    partTag = null;
  } else {
    partTag = setInterval(function() {
      var tag = document.getElementById('inputTag').value;
      var partyNameTag = tag.split(" ")[tagLength];
      document.getElementsByClassName('partyTagInput')[0].value = partyNameTag;
      tagMaxLength = tag.split(" ").length;
      if (tagMaxLength == tagLength + 1) {
        tagLength = 0;
      } else {
        tagLength++;
      }

    }, 500);
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" class="partyTagInput" maxlength="49" value="">
<br>
<input type="text" id="inputTag" maxlength="35" value="TEXT HERE">
<br>
<button id="buttonTag" style="width: 30%;">BUTTON</button>
```

sorry my bad english

Comment: What returns undefined? I'm trying your code and it works. If I write 3 words instead of "TEXT HERE", then click the button, I see my 3 words cycling. What's wrong?

Comment: If the text is changed why it's cycling it will sometimes return undefined. but most of the time it will return undefined when text is removed.

Comment: @lockner if you want it to stop the interval when the text is cleared, then you will have to clearInterval() when the condition met.

Answer (score 1):

Must be `tagMaxLength = tag.split(" ").length-1;`

as the indexes in arrays starts from 0;

you will get undefined for partyNameTag in `var partyNameTag = tag.split(" ")[tagLength];` when tagLength = length of array

```js
var tagButton = document.getElementById("buttonTag");
tagButton.addEventListener("click", partyTagChange);

var partTag = null,
  tagLength = 0,
  tagMaxLength = 0;

function partyTagChange() {
  clearInterval(partTag);
  if (partTag !== null) {
    partTag = null;
  } else {
    partTag = setInterval(function() {
      var tag = document.getElementById('inputTag').value;
      var partyNameTag = tag.split(" ")[tagLength];
      document.getElementsByClassName('partyTagInput')[0].value = partyNameTag;
      tagMaxLength = tag.split(" ").length-1;
      if (!partyNameTag || tagMaxLength == tagLength) {
        tagLength = 0;
      } else {
        tagLength++;
      }

    }, 500);
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" class="partyTagInput" maxlength="49" value="">
<br>
<input type="text" id="inputTag" maxlength="35" value="TEXT HERE">
<br>
<button id="buttonTag" style="width: 30%;">BUTTON</button>
```

Comment: I entered 3 words but I can see only 2 cycling

Comment: This works but i still get an error undefined if text is removed for the input why it's cycling.

Comment: @lockner fixed that also. However its better you clearInterval rather tagLength = 0.

Answer (score 0):

Just add the check `tagMaxLength == 1` which fixes your `undefined` issue.

```js
var tagButton = document.getElementById("buttonTag");
tagButton.addEventListener("click", partyTagChange);

var partTag = null,
  tagLength = 0,
  tagMaxLength = 0;

function partyTagChange() {

  clearInterval(partTag);
  if (partTag !== null) {
    partTag = null;
  } else {
    partTag = setInterval(function() {
      var tag = document.getElementById('inputTag').value;
        var partyNameTag = tag.split(" ")[tagLength];
        document.getElementsByClassName('partyTagInput')[0].value = partyNameTag;
        tagMaxLength = tag.split(" ").length;
        if (tagMaxLength == 1 || tagMaxLength == tagLength + 1) {
          tagLength = 0;
        } else {
          tagLength++;
        }

    }, 500);
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" class="partyTagInput" maxlength="49" value="">
<br>
<input type="text" id="inputTag" maxlength="35" value="TEXT HERE">
<br>
<button id="buttonTag" style="width: 30%;">BUTTON</button>
```